# Apache custom 404 page that returns 404 error

Tags: apache2, http-status-code-404, custom-error-pages

I have a custom 404 error page on my apache (404.php) and it works normally, but if someone or any search engine requests the `/404.php` page, the server returns `200 (OK)`, because the page actually exists.

I have already put the `Disallow: /404.php` on my `robots.txt` file to prevent Google from indexing that page, but I'd like to return 404, including to this page request.

Is there a way to also return 404 when someone reaches the `404.php` directly?

Comment: Is the link you are providing in the .htaccess file absolute (http://server/404.php) or relative?

Comment: Relative. `ErrorDocument 404 /404.php`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just whipped this up really quickly:

```
<?
 header("HTTP/1.1 404");
 echo "ERROR"; // Put the contents of your 404 page here.
?>
```

I checked it in Chrome, and this will return a 404 code in the header, and let you write whatever you'd like to the rest of the page. Just put the `header` function at the beginning of the page.